# Storing the plots in a folder while running the MATLAB program?

Tags: storage, matlab

In my MATLAB program I have to run a for loop for 500 times and each time the loop runs it plots a graph, so If I run the program there will be 500 (.fig files) and that may hang my system.

So is there any way that I can save the output which are produced after each loop automatically in some folder?.

If there is some procedure, a reference to that procedure will be very much helpful!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`saveas`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html?requestedDomain=nl.mathworks.com) method.

For example, to save a simple bar plot as a `png` file:

```
x = [2 4 7 2 4 5 2 5 1 4];
bar(x);
saveas(gcf,'Barchart.png')
```

or as an `eps` file:

```
saveas(gcf,'Barchart','epsc')
```

Make sure you use a filename that depends on something that varies in each loop iteration to not overwrite the file. You can use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to create the new file name, e.g. to save an `eps` file:

```
for k = 1:500
    filename = sprintf('%s_%d','Barchart',k);
    % Create the plot
    saveas(gcf,filename,'epsc')
end
```

See the link to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html?requestedDomain=nl.mathworks.com) for more configurations and filetypes.

Comment: how to change the name of the file in each iteration, like barchart1,barchart2,barchart3,... ??

Comment: @BAYMAX: You can, for example, use `sprintf` to do this. I added an example in the answer.